# gcloud auth application-default login refresh token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth

When a developper use multiple times `gcloud auth application-default login` , without revoking between the calls. The `application_credentials.json` gets replaced, but does it mean that the refresh_token that were present in the deleted credentials are still valid and there are several valid orphan refresh_token ?

Is there anything special that GCP performs to reduce the validity of the refresh_token when using `gcloud auth application-default login` to avoid having a lot of unused valid refresh_token ?

Comment: Have you verified that there are unused valid refresh_tokens? What problem are you trying to solve with ADC?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't refresh_token revocation. But I might be wrong.

Comment: if you do gcloud auth application-default revoke (and before that kept a copy of the .json) and try to use it again by putting back the file at the proper place for adc you’ll see that you won’t be able to get an access token. However if you just delete the file and do the same manipulation (without revoke command) , you’ll see that everything work.

Comment: That’s why I’m asking if there is anything put in place such that refresh token doesn’t work after some amount of time in case the developer doesn’t use the revoke command, in my eyes it’s like leaving your credential plain text on your machine because the refresh token can give you new access tokens

Comment: Correct, but that is the problem with all credentials. The environment where credentials are stored and/or used must also be secure. If I can access your desktop, then I can also see your source code, read emails, trash your machine, etc.